# CSS3 Media Query not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am having a bit of trouble with a media query not working at all.  I have the viewport meta tag inserted into the head of my HTML file:

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

I also have my media query following right under the standard CSS declaration:

> ```
> >  #serviceIcons {
> > 
> >     position: relative; 
> >     top: 25px;
> >     width: 250px;
> >     }
> >
> >     @media only screen and (max-width: 768px;) {
> >     
> >     #serviceIcons {
> >     
> >         position: relative;
> >         top: 25px;
> >         width: 250px;
> >         -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
> >         border-radius: 50%;
> >         -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0px 0 10px;
> >         box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0 0 10px;
> >     }
> >     
> >     }
> ```

I've tried just about everything I could find by searching Google, and no suggestions I have come across have worked. I'd like to add that I am using Bootstrap as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: At least show some HTML!!

Comment: Run your CSS through a CSS linter or validator, such as https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the semi colon

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
```

Comment: these tired eyeballs of mine! that worked perfectly. thank you for your input!